# Is it a bad idea to put apache conf files in my rails app's config directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have a dedicated CentOS server. I manage all my users, apps, and virtual hosts manually. I'm using Apache 2.2.3 and Passenger 3.0.7 to serve my apps. I have a typical httpd.conf file in `/etc/httpd/conf/` that includes all `*.conf` files in my `/etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/` directory. Normally for each app I create a new sample-domain.com.conf file in the vhosts directory.

However, I have a particular app that needs frequent apache configuration changes, and I'd like it to be more a part of my app and its version control. So I've moved my apache configuration file into the apps config directory. I added a script to my Capistrano deploy.rb that sets the permissions on the apache conf file in the app to 755. I added an include line in my vhosts that includes the symlinked current version of the apache conf file from the app.

Which brings me to my simple question: is this safe or a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For frequent config changes in Apache, consider using a .htaccess file instead. Changing .conf files requires bouncing/hupping the server, and if a .conf file has an error, that'll kill the whole server and take down all sites. A .htaccess error will take down just the one site/directory where the file is.

Comment: It's currently 479 lines long. Is that a bit much for .htaccess or does it not make a difference?

Comment: A bit. but if only small portions of the file change, then extract only the frequently updated bits for the .htaccess file. Remember that .htaccess overrides .conf settings, so it's not a big deal to put the changes into .htaccess only and only occassionaly "port" the changes back to the main .conf.